# Unable to upload new file as a product

Tags: uploads, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I'm trying to upload an XML file (RSS feed) as part of a product in the WP-Ecommerce plug-in.

The idea being that a customer buying the product would be given this XML file to download which ideally launch iTunes to download the balance as part of a podcast.

I can't seem to upload the .XML feed file.  I can upload other file types without a problem, but that one seems to be blocked.  Where would I go to allow .XML files to be uploaded?  Is it a WP-ECommerce thing, a WordPress thing, or perhaps something on the hosted server itself?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress does not allow uploads of .xml files but you can add it by adding a mime type for it.  This worked for me:

```
function addUploadXML($mimes) {
    $mimes = array_merge($mimes, array('xml' => 'text/xml'));.
    return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'addUploadXML');
```

Also, when I researched the mime type, I came up with a number of different suggestions for what to use as a mime type for xml.  I just used 'text/xml' but I also saw 'application/rss+xml' and 'application/xml' among others.